# 2011 Cadillac Escalade Can't Go Over 80

Tags: service, cadillac

I have a 2011 Cadillac Escalade ESV Premium.  When I bought it, the Service Suspension System error was on the dash display.  I also learned that you cannot go over 80mph with that error code.  It has some type of safety feature to limit it.  I replaced the suspension system air compressor, which corrected the Service Suspension System error, but the vehicle still limits only to 80mph.  There are currently no error codes or dash messages.  How do I get past this 80mph limitation?  You also cannot set the cruise control over 75 as part of the safety feature.  I would really like to get that corrected. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to reset the ECU by unplugging the battery and leaving it sit for 20-30 minutes?

Comment: I haven't been able to test it out yet, but I did disconnect the battery, and re checked the electrical connections to the shocks and the compressor.  I will try to get it out tonight to test.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I just got out and tested this.  The same problem exists.  The Service Suspension System error is gone, but still can't go over 80 or set cruise above 75.   Any additional thoughts or tests I can do?

Comment: Do you have the ability to read codes from the system? Also, did you use OEM parts as replacements?

Comment: I have an ODB2 scanner, but nothing comes back on that.  I used a Dorman 949-099 Air Suspension Compressor for the replacement part.

Comment: That could be the problem. I understand if the system does not detect OEM parts, it might still keep it in the "limited MPH" mode. From what I was reading, it seems this has to do with the suspension part of it, but have not seen anything stating the compressor would cause the same issue. There are supposed to be work around kits for the shocks, but not sure for the compressor.

Comment: From what I read, I should still get a dash message, either the suspension one, or the Limited Speed one.  I have neither at the moment.  I'll put some miles and ignition cycles on it, see if that changes anything.

Comment: Upon further testing, I found that the service suspension light only shows when I start the vehicle and it is below 50 degrees.  I'm not sure what the cold has to do with it, but there is something there.